# Flip barplot axes

Tags: r

How can I to turn vertically the names "fast" and "slow" through 'barplot()' ?

```
barplot(table(mode))
```

[image]

Comment: dude, you had a totally different question >_<

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: AK88, there was an old question that I mistakenly published. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the "las" parameter to change the orientation of the labels

```
barplot(table(mode), las=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("1.3.43.33", "2.2.43.33", "1.3.43.33", "66.3.43.33")
df = as.data.frame(table(x))
df

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = Freq))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Hi! Please provide some explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just write :

```
barplot(table(x), las = 2)
```

where `x` is your vector of data :

```
x <- c("1.3.43.33", "2.2.43.33", "1.3.43.33", "66.3.43.33")
```